# remove row from another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a listview which is inflated by custom array adapter and onclick takes it to another activity with the data related to that row .After clicking on delete its supposed to delete the item from the list and get back to the list.

I am using the code below for this :

```
int deleteposition=CustomizedListView.deleteposition;
CustomizedListView.list.removeViewAt(deleteposition);
CustomizedListView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

finish();
```

**But there is an error at this line :**

```
 CustomizedListView.list.removeViewAt(deleteposition);
```

Please Tell me how to fix it ?

Logcat Details:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: removeViewAt(int) is not supported in AdapterView
at android.widget.AdapterView.removeViewAt(AdapterView.java:511)
    at com.example.androidhive.openedmsg$1.onClick(openedmsg.java:35)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The entire Code :

CustomizedListView.class

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=20/json";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    static ListView list;
    static LazyAdapter adapter;

    HashMap<String, String> map;

    public static  String newactivityno;

    public static int deleteposition;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);


        try {
            JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray arr3 = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                JSONObject arr8 = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");

                JSONObject arr10 = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");

                    JSONObject e12 = arr3.getJSONObject(0);

            // creating new HashMap
             map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  e12.getString("label"));

            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, arr8.getString("label"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, arr10.getString("label"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Network communication error!", 5).show();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                HashMap<String, String> o= (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

                           //   Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("title") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                                deleteposition=position;
                             newactivityno= o.get("title");
                             Intent ii= new Intent(getBaseContext(),newactivity.class); 
                                startActivity(ii);

            }
        });     
    }   
}
```

newactivity.class

```
public class newactivity extends Activity{


     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);


            TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);

            Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            tv2.setText(CustomizedListView.newactivityno);


            bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int deleteposition=CustomizedListView.deleteposition;
                    CustomizedListView.list.removeViewAt(deleteposition);
                    CustomizedListView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    finish();

                }
            });
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this problem in the wrong manner.  Rather than remove the View from the AdapterView, simply remove the data from the data set and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  (This will remove the unwanted View automatically.)

Comment: Thank You Sir that worked. Made songlist static and added the code below in newactivity. **CustomizedListView.songsList.remove(deleteposition);**

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. You can also try deleting the data from the adapter: `CustomizedListView.adapter.remove(deleteposition);` This way you don't have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Using the above code it give me an error below remove and 2 options given are to create method remove(int) in lazyadapter or add cast to method receiver .Sir Am I doing the same thing you suggested ?

Comment: Yes, `CustomizedListView.songsList.remove(deleteposition);` and `CustomizedListView.adapter.remove(deleteposition);` are almost identical. I don't know which LazyAdapter you are using, so I don't know if it has `remove()`. But if `songsList.remove()` works then use this. :)

Comment: Thank You Sir Its the same class of lazyAdapter class I have posted above .Thanks again I will use this for now.Have a great day.