# Remove item from another activity using button

Tags: android

**The problem: I want to remove a item from my listview using a button in another activity.**

I have tried several kinds of code, but it just doesn't seem to work.
Right know I use serializable to bundle the object to the other activity.
But I don't know how to remove it, from the other activity.

Can anybody help me with that?
Can I use the button from the second activity, in the first activity to delete the item from the listview?

Class A where I got my ListView

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    Button exit;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    final List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override``
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

        // Registration numbers
        final String[] title = new String[] { "XMT 123", "KLE 456", "CKL 789",
                "MRP 012", "DSV 345" };

        // Name of the truck drivers
        final String[] subtitle = new String[] { "Peter Lund", "Hans Larsson",
                "Erik Petersson", "Bjørn Lundal", "Lars Svensson" };

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            Map<String, String> datalist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datalist.put("title", title[i]);
            datalist.put("subtitle", subtitle[i]);
            data.add(datalist);
        }

        // getDataInList();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] { "title",
                        "subtitle" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2 });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
                        InformationActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("updateReg", title[position].toString());
                intent.putExtra("updateName", subtitle[position].toString());

            }

        });

        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Closes the application
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
```

Class B where I got my accept button.
When I click accept, the item from the listview in Class A should be removed.

```
public class InformationActivity extends Activity {
    TextView name;
    TextView reg;
    TextView product;
    TextView productNo;
    Button accept;
    Button edit;
    Button exit;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    ListView list;
    String result;
    EditText search;
    int requestCode = 1;

    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    Context context = InformationActivity.this;
    ArrayList<Materials> materialList = new ArrayList<Materials>();

    // Materials
    final static String[] material = new String[] { "Betong", "Grus", "Järn",
            "Metall", "Grus fin", "Grus grov", "Sten" };

    // Material numbers
    final static String[] materialNo = new String[] { "123", "234", "345",
            "456", "567", "789", "012" };

    private void getDataInList() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            Materials mats = new Materials(result, result);
            mats.setMaterialName(material[i]);
            // mats.setMaterialNo(material[i]);
            materialList.add(mats);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information_activity);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        product = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product);
        productNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productNo);
        accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String selected_item = extras.getString("updateReg");
        reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        reg.setText(selected_item);

        Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String selected_item1 = extras1.getString("updateName");
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(selected_item1);

        getDataInList();

        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        InformationActivity.this);
                popup.setTitle("Välj ny artikel");

                // Search field
                final EditText search = new EditText(context);
                popup.setView(search);
                search.setHint("Sök här...");

                popup.setSingleChoiceItems(material, -1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                materialList.get(which);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        material[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                result = material[which];

                            }

                        });

                // PositiveButton, updates the material info field.
                popup.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                product.setText(result);

                            }
                        });

                // NegativeButton, closes the pop-up.
                popup.setNegativeButton("Avbryt",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                dialog = popup.create();
                dialog.show();

            }

        });``

        //Remove item
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: how are you determining which list item to be deleted at the moment?

Comment: IF you are using bundle activity B should put to it information about item that will be removed and for example in activity A in onResult method item should be deleted

Comment: can you post your code ? 
just delete data from list that you sending to adapter and then: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all.
I found another solution thanks to [remove row from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821664/remove-row-from-another-activity)

Class A

```
   public class ListActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        Button exit;

        static List<ListItems> items = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
        public static int deletePos;
        static ListAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);

            // Registration numbers
            final String[] title = new String[] { "XMT 123", "KLE 456", "CKL 789",
                    "MRP 012", "DSV 345" };

            // Name of the truck drivers
            final String[] subtitle = new String[] { "Peter Lund", "Hans Larsson",
                    "Erik Petersson", "Bjørn Lundal", "Lars Svensson" };

            items = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
            for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
                ListItems s = new ListItems(title[i], subtitle[i]);
                items.add(s);

            }

            adapter = new ListAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    items);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
                            InformationActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("updateReg", title[position].toString());
                    intent.putExtra("updateName", subtitle[position].toString());
                    deletePos = position;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });
            exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                // Closes the application
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

    }


Class B

public class InformationActivity extends Activity {
    TextView name;
    TextView reg;
    TextView product;
    TextView productNo;
    Button accept;
    Button edit;
    Button exit;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    ListView list;
    String result;
    EditText search;


    Context context = InformationActivity.this;
    ArrayList<Materials> materialList = new ArrayList<Materials>();

    // Materials
    final static String[] material = new String[] { "Betong", "Grus", "Järn",
            "Metall", "Grus fin", "Grus grov", "Sten" };

    // Material numbers
    final static String[] materialNo = new String[] { "123", "234", "345",
            "456", "567", "789", "012" };

    private void getDataInList() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            Materials mats = new Materials(result, result);
            mats.setMaterialName(material[i]);
            // mats.setMaterialNo(material[i]);
            materialList.add(mats);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information_activity);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        product = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product);
        productNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productNo);
        accept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String selected_item = extras.getString("updateReg");
        reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        reg.setText(selected_item);

        Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String selected_item1 = extras1.getString("updateName");
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(selected_item1);
        getDataInList();

        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        InformationActivity.this);
                popup.setTitle("Välj ny artikel");

                // Search field
                final EditText search = new EditText(context);
                popup.setView(search);
                search.setHint("Sök här...");

                popup.setSingleChoiceItems(material, -1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                materialList.get(which);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        material[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                result = material[which];

                            }

                        });

                // PositiveButton, updates the material info field.
                popup.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                product.setText(result);

                            }
                        });

                // NegativeButton, closes the pop-up.
                popup.setNegativeButton("Avbryt",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                dialog = popup.create();
                dialog.show();

            }

        });

        // Remove item
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int deletePos = ListActivity.deletePos;
                ListActivity.items.remove(deletePos);
                ListActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                finish();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly remove the item from the view, but from the data displayed in it.

For example if your `ListView` is displaying items from an `ArrayList`, just remove the item in the ArrayList from you `Activity` *B*, and call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when back in the Activity *A*, which contains the adapter.

You can remove items by accessing to the ArrayList or by overriding the `remove()` method if you have only access to the adapter (assuming your adapter extends `ArrayAdapter`).

Also, you may have to override usefull Adapter methods like `getCount()`, `getView()`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I found another solution.